# Do I need a POP3/IMAP server running to use PHPMailer?

Tags: php, imap, pop3, dovecot

We have deployed Google Apps for our email so don't use POP/IMAP.

However, some of our website's scripts (WordPress, OpenCart) use PHP mail function to send emails.

Do I need to keep running a POP3/IMAP server like Dovecot running or can I safely turn it off?

On that note, can I close POP3/IMAP ports safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POP/IMAP are for **retrieving** email. For sending, which is what PHPMailer is doing, you need an SMTP server, e.g. postfix, sendmail, exim.

Comment: Full featured SMTP server is not required, MTA/SMTP-relay is.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need just MTA, so SMTP is only required protocol.

IMAP/POP3 is for receiving mails from your existing mailbox.